# Return syllables of words hyphenated - in R

Tags: r, hyphenation

I have been working for a few days on this and not making as much headway as I would like. I know Franklin M. Liang's hyphenation algorithm implemented in a number of [languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphenation_algorithm). Yet none of these are R.

Even if there was an implementation in R, I am not really sure if it would be doing exactly what I want since I am interested in identifying syllables and not just acoustically and visually appealing locations for line breaks.

My ideal implementation would be the following:

```
w = c('country', 'someone',  'merely')
syllables(w) 
[1] "coun-try" "some-one" "mere-ly"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liang's hyphenation algorithm is implemented in the [koRpus](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/koRpus/) package. The vignette states that

> "the function hyphen() takes objects of class kRp.tagged and applies an hyphenation algorithm (Liang, 1983) to each word."